# Solve $\int_{K}^{\infty}yf(y)\,dy$ where $y=A\exp\left(\sigma x-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$ and $x\sim N(0,1)$

Tags: integral

> I need to solve
>   $$\int_{K}^{\infty} y f(y)\,dy $$
>   where $y = A\exp\left(\sigma x-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$, $x\sim N(0,1)$, $K\geq0$.

Any help?

Comment: What is $f?$ It doesn't look like you've defined that function.

Comment: Try to write down the PDF of y via the PDF of normal distribution and plug it in the integral

Answer (score 2):

Start with deriving the cdf of $Y$:
$$P(Y \leq y) = P(A \exp{\sigma x + \sigma^2/2} \leq y) = P(x  \leq \frac{1}{\sigma}(\ln y - \ln A - \sigma^2/2)) = \Phi(\frac{1}{\sigma}(\ln y - \ln A - \sigma^2/2)).$$

Then we can get the pdf of $Y$, which you denote, $f(y)$, by differentiating:

$$P(Y=y) = \frac{d}{dy} P(Y \leq y)  = \phi(\frac{1}{\sigma}(\ln y - \ln A - \sigma^2/2))\frac{1}{\sigma y}.$$

Then we can rewrite the integral as

$$\int_K^{\infty} y \phi(\frac{1}{\sigma}(\ln y - \ln A - \sigma^2/2))\frac{1}{\sigma y}dy$$

$$ =\frac{1}{\sigma} \int_K^{\infty} \phi(\frac{1}{\sigma}(\ln y - \ln A - \sigma^2/2))dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_K^{\infty} \exp\{\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(\ln y - \ln A - \sigma^2/2)^2\}  dy$$